# Install PostgreSQL Driver in SQL Developer

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use MAC OSX (El Capitan) and I would like to connect to my local PostgreSQL database via Oracle SQL Developer.

1. I've installed Oracle SQL Developer (Version 4.1.3.20, Build 78)
2. I've configured PostgreSQL driver in SQL Developer (Version postgresql-9.4.1207.jar).
3. I created a New Connection in SQL Developer.

It connects fine to DB and I can see my tables, the problem is that I cannot see my functions\stored procedures. it empty...

If I connect to the same schema via pgAdmin3 then I can see everything. so it's not a problem with DB.

Has anyone encountered this bizarre problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Being an Oracle tool, I don't believe it will work perfectly with non-Oracle databases. You weren't even able to connect to a 3rd party DBMS before version 4.x

Comment: It works well with showing tables and even triggers, but no sequences or functions :-(